# Rails: friendly_id and to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, slug, friendly-id

I have a collection of model objects that I am trying to return JSON for.  E.G

```
@regions.to_json(:only => [:id, :name ])
```

that works fine.

If I try to use :

```
@regions.to_json(:only => [:friendly_id, :name ])
```

then nothing is returned for the friendly_id.  The model does have:

```
has_friendly_id :name, :use_slug => true
```

So I am wondering what I am missing - or if I am not allowed to use
friendly_id's in to_json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
@regions.to_json(:only => [:id, :cached_slug])
```

Comment: Yup, thanks - had just tried that and was about to update ;)  Perfecto. thanks.